# How to **FIX** a value to the DBGrid's header heigth?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, tdbgrid

When the user selects the header of my grid, I would like to **bold** the column header of the grid. 
I use the following code to achieve this:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var I: Integer;
begin
  //Prevent multiple clicks!  
  if fsBold in Column.Title.Font.Style then
    Exit;

  for I:= 0 to Column.Collection.Count-1 do
    (Column.Collection.Items[I] as TColumn)
            .Title.Font.Style := [];
  Column.Title.Font.Style := [fsBold];
end;
```

This code is working fine.

In the `OnFormCreate` I've defined the following header height:

```
type
  DBGridHack = class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGridHack(DBGrid1).RowHeights[0] := 45;
end;
```

When I click in the Title, the procedure `InternalLayout.MeasureTitleHeights` changes the size back to the original.
Thus, every time I change the font style I need to redefine the value for `RowHeight[0]`.

The code would look like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);
var I: Integer;
begin
  //Prevent multiple clicks!  
  if fsBold in Column.Title.Font.Style then
    Exit;

  for I:= 0 to Column.Collection.Count-1 do
    (Column.Collection.Items[I] as TColumn)
            .Title.Font.Style := [];
  Column.Title.Font.Style := [fsBold];

  //Every time!!
  DBGridHack(DBGrid1).RowHeights[0] := 45;
end;
```

There is another issue when the user redefine the Column's width, in this case the `RowHeight[0]` also returns to the original value. The only way I imagine to solve this, is to inherit DBGrid and override `ColWidthsChanged`, but how much more methods will I have to override?

Why this happens? 
Is this a bug, or is my code bugged?
Is there a way to workaround this?

In a simple question.

How to **FIX** a value to the DBGrid's header heigth?

Comment: It's not a bug, it is how the control is designed.

Comment: Stop using TDBGrid and use a real grid :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy hahaha, nice! what do you suggest?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Do you have an idea about how many events I'll have to override to make things work?

Comment: If you don't mind paying for one, DevExpress Quantumgrid is really good. But there are many free Grids out there...

Comment: @Matheus - Not exactly. But doesn't look quite there yet with a quick browse; font change, anything that leads to columns update such as column index change..

Comment: A workaround could be to override Layoutchanged with an interposer class `procedure TDBGrid.LayoutChanged;
begin
  inherited;
 if RowHeights[0]<>50 then  RowHeights[0] := 50;
end;`

Comment: @bummi By looking into DBGrids.pas I can partially agree with you. There is a small problem: when the user calls `DBGrid1.Columns.RebuildColumns`, this is the only issue I can't solve by overriding `Layoutchanged`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Is my solution a good approach?

Comment: @Matheus - I can't really say so from here. Conceptually painting is for painting and it's generally a good idea to avoid anything that could trigger painting while painting. However you might have ran out of options and your solution might be working good, it's your call eventually.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Indeed. I cannot think about another solution. I guess the best option should be to change the component as whosrdaddy said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like if I override the `Paint` procedure, it will work as expected.
I don't know if there is side effects about this solution.

This is the code for the custom DBGrid. Please if this is not a good solution I would appreciate if you state it so.

```
TDBGrid1 = class(TDBGrid)
  private
    FTitleFixedHeight: Integer;
    function CheckHeaderFixed: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    property TitleFixedHeight: Integer read FTitleFixedHeight write FTitleFixedHeight;
  end;

function TDBGrid1.CheckHeaderFixed: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (TitleFixedHeight <> 0) and (RowHeights[0] <> TitleFixedHeight);
end;

procedure TDBGrid1.Paint;
begin
  if CheckHeaderFixed then
  begin
    RowHeights[0] := TitleFixedHeight;
  end;    
  inherited;
end;
```